# mouseenter event handler does not work the first time the event is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a function to remove a class with the contents `display:hidden;` when the mouse enters a certain part of the DOM to show a menu. Now, when the page loads and I initially hover over the area, the event doesn't fire. BUT, if I move my mouse on it once, move away, then move back to the targeted element. It fires fine and the menu is unhidden.

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWYevq

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#kDropdown, .hidden-dropdown' ).mouseleave(function(e) {
        window.k = setTimeout(function(){
           $('.hidden-dropdown').addClass("hide_k");
        }, 250)
      }).mouseenter(function(e) {
        if(window.k){
          console.log("test")
          clearTimeout(window.k)
          $(".hidden-dropdown").removeClass("hide_k");
        }
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: It works even if the `window.k` is compared to anything. I **highly** doubt if this condition is obligatory here.

#### In your particular case:

`window.k` was returning `undefined` (false) value when you were hovering the box for the first time, that's why it was unable to **pass** the condition - the list was not appearing.

Check **[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZKJyE?editors=1010)**, open the console and hover the box. The first log will be the `undefined` value.

If you hover the box for the **second** time, the list will appear because `window.k` is already set inside the `mouseleave()` function - it won't return `undefined` (false) from now on.

The working solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#kDropdown, .hidden-dropdown').mouseleave(function(e) {
    window.k = setTimeout(function() {
      $('.hidden-dropdown').addClass("hide_k");
    }, 250);
  }).mouseenter(function(e) {
    console.log("test")
    clearTimeout(window.k)
    $(".hidden-dropdown").removeClass("hide_k");
  });
})
```

```css
.hide_k {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='kDropdown' style="background-color: black; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>

<div class="hide_k hidden-dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>LIST</li>
    <li>THAT</li>
    <li>IS</li>
    <li>HIDDEN</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need this line?

```
if(window.k) {
```

The first time that you enter, that variable is not assigned, so the event is not fired.
If you remove that line the effect works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

it's not firing on first time because there is no `window.k` yet.

once `mouseleave` its get assigned. so working from second time on wards.

to get this work, move  `$(".hidden-dropdown").removeClass("hide_k");` outside the `if(window.k)` condition.

Here is a working [**Code Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpegyK)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#kDropdown, .hidden-dropdown').mouseleave(function(e) {
    window.k = setTimeout(function() {
      $('.hidden-dropdown').addClass("hide_k");
    }, 250)
  }).mouseenter(function(e) {
    if (window.k) {
      clearTimeout(window.k)
    }
    $(".hidden-dropdown").removeClass("hide_k");
  });
})
```

```css
.hide_k { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='kDropdown' style="background-color: black; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>

<div class="hide_k hidden-dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li>LIST</li>
    <li>THAT</li>
    <li>IS</li>
    <li>HIDDEN</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working the first time is because you don't set up window.k yet.  Change this:

```
$('#kDropdown, .hidden-dropdown' ).mouseleave(function(e) {
    window.k = setTimeout(function(){
```

to this:

```
window.k=true;
$('#kDropdown, .hidden-dropdown' ).mouseleave(function(e) {
        window.k = setTimeout(function(){
```

What is happening is that you are checking if(window.k){} on mouseenter, and when the first "enter" happens, no mouseleave has happened yet to set window.k.  Therefore your if(window.k) check in mouseenter returns false the first time.  But then you leave the box, window.k gets set, and then it works from there becuase your if(window.k) statement then returns true (as the first mouseleave event finally set it).  Hope that makes sense!  Basically it is a timing issue, and you just need to set window.k = true before you do anything else.